# SMS messages just have "null"

Tags: sms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SMS messages from one contact displayed as “null”](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9577/sms-messages-from-one-contact-displayed-as-null)

I have a Samsung Galaxy 5.  A coworker sent me a contact from his Nokia phone, which showed up as "null", and now all other SMS's from him also come through only as "null."  I've tried deleting the thread, deleting the contact, turning the phone off and then on... Any help would be appreciated.

J

Comment: Did you add the contact again with a name after you deleted it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

> delete his contact

then

> Settings > Applications > Manage Applications > Select the Messaging App
>
> Choose 'Clear Data' and also 'Clear Cache'.

**N.B. you will lose all data / txt msg's in your phone**

(don't forget to write their number down to save as new afterwards!)